# Availability of Reactive LdapTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, spring-webflux

Is there a way to achieve what **LdapTemplate** does for in a reactive manner for Spring Webflux? If a tutorial exist that would be great!

For example how to achieve `ldapTemplate.search()` in Spring Webflux in a non blocking reactive way?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Spring Webflux, but it doesn't look like `LdapTemplate` provides 'reactivity' out of the box, though this should be possible to achieve with a bit of extra code.

LDAP supports pagination (see the [Simple Paged Results Control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control)), which may be useful in offloading some of the back pressure from your service onto the LDAP server.

You can try looking into the [`PagedResultsDirContextProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html), which implements the control and can be passed to the [`search()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#search-javax.naming.Name-java.lang.String-javax.naming.directory.SearchControls-org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper-org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextProcessor-) function. However, it may not provide fine enough control over the paging, so it may not be suitable for this task. In this case it will be necessary to forgo `LdapTemplate` and instead use the lower-level [JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html) equivalent.

Comment: yes, seems like we do not have a reactive-ldaptemplate yet. And as you suggested the way-around to this seems like making use of webflux's way of handing over the work load to an different thread pool for maintaing non-blocking behavior (bit of extra code indeed)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation, I basically created an another spring boot application separate for my LDAP needs and expose it as a REST API using spring LDAP template